# Cast Swift / Objective C

Tags: swift, casting

I'm trying to translate a code from Objective-C to swift. Every now and then I run into problems with castings.

Here is an example:

There's a class deriving from NSObject which is supposed to simulate a UITableViewDataSource:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ReloadDataWatcher : NSObject

- (void)reloadData;
- (BOOL)didReceiveReloadData;

@end
```

Here the class is used getting casted to UITableView

```
- (void)testQuestionListCausesTableReloadOnAvatarNotification {
    ReloadDataWatcher *fakeTableView = [[ReloadDataWatcher alloc] init];
    dataSource.tableView = (UITableView *)fakeTableView;
    [dataSource avatarStoreDidUpdateContent: nil];
    XCTAssertTrue([fakeTableView didReceiveReloadData], @"...");
}
```

Everything fine under Objective - C

Doing the same in Swift:

Here the class:

```
class ReloadDataWatcher: NSObject {
    var didReloadData: Bool = false
    func reloadData() {
...    }
}
```

Leads to a "ReloadDataWatcher" is not convertible to UITableView Compiler Error.

```
 func testQuestionListCausesTableReloadOnAvatarNotification() {
        let fakeTableView : ReloadDataWatcher = ReloadDataWatcher()
        dataSource.tableView = fakeTableView as UITableView
        ...
    }
```

Why is that so ? Can I no longer cast from sub-class to a another subclass with the same parent (NSObject) ?
What would a solution be in that case?

Comment: Tbh, it doesn't seem right to be able to cast your `ReloadDataWatcher` instance to a `UITableView` since even if it represents the same object for you, the compiler can't understand it. Also, if you don't want to bother to translate your Objective-C code to Swift, you can create a bridging header that does it automatically. More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)